# VsAddin or T4 for code generation (VS 2008)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, code-generation, t4

I have build an Addin for code generation (C#, VS 08) for our team.

The addin creates a new menu entry if i click on a file in the solution explorer.
There i can choose a destination test project where the 2 files are generated to.

For the code generation process i need informations from the selected item in the solution explorer (like Interfaces, generic types of the class declaration).

My source class looks like

```
public class CustomerLogic : BaseBL<T1, T2, T3>, ICustomerBL
```

The *generated* container class

```
public class CustomerContainer : BaseBLDummyContainer<T1, T2, T3>
```

The *generated* dummy class looks like

```
public class CustomerBLDummy : BaseBLDummy<T1, T2, T3, CustomerContainer>, ICustomer
```

---

How i realized it?

I created two templates (container and dummy), put placeholder to the spaces so the two template files look like

Containertemplate

```
public class $Classname$ : BaseBLDummyContainer<$T1$, $T2$, $T3$>
```

Dummytemplate

```
public class $Classname$ : BaseBLDummy<$T1$, $T2$, $T3$, $TContainer$>$, TInterface$
```

To generate the templates i have writen some code to

- create the files
- add them to the destination project
- create methods if needed

You can see, a "lot" of work to do only to generate some code.

1. Now i consider if the generation with T4 is a better solution for my situation?
2. Does i have some benefits of the T4 mechanism ? (I've only see some T4 samples in combination with EF or database related generation)
3. Should i be more flexible with T4?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make an either/or choice here 'k', you can mix and match add-ins and T4.

T4 has a very simple UI binding to Visual Studio out of the box, that just uses the Custom Tool mechanism (IVsSingleFileGenerator) to connect a template file to an output file in the project.  (See T4Toolbox community project for more complex output).

However, T4 also exposes a service interface in VS (STextTemplating/ITextTemplating) that you can use from both VS add-ins and VS packages.

So you could keep your add-in's entry point and core way of working, but use T4 to provide the template engine and avoid having to maintain that part yourself.   You'd likely use the
<#@ parameter #> directive to pass replacement parameters in to your template for T1, T2, T3 etc.

Hope this gives you some ideas for options to move forward.

Comment: thanks for the short explanation. I will play a little bit. Ive downloaded the needed stuff and started right now. I first think i write a little code to collect all needed informations from the source file and for the template, put it in and data structure, import it to the template file and reference to the fields in the template.